# Fingerprint enrolment for hundreds of users on Android and syncronise them to a main server

Tags: android, ionic-framework, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, digital-persona-sdk

I am researching if it would be possible to create a fingerprint enrolment APP on Android using ideally a hybrid framework, like Ionic. The problem is that normally the fingerprint authentication for mobiles/tablets is thought to be used for just a few users and they are stored locally.

My idea is to be able to send the fingerprints to a main server and then syncronise them with the rest of the devices, so I am not sure if this would be possible with Android, or I should use a Linux PC with a fingerprint attached to it and create the software there.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do using the built-in fingerprint reader that tablets have or I should choose the second option and use a PC with the reader attached?

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure if this would be possible with Android

It is not.

> Does anyone know if this is possible to do using the built-in fingerprint reader that tablets have

It is not.

> I should choose the second option and use a PC with the reader attached?

Whether you use a PC or a tablet does not matter. What matters is that you are using an external fingerprint reader, one with an SDK that allows you to get access to the biometric data. You will need to check with the manufacturer of the fingerprint reader to determine what platforms it supports.

Also, please consult with qualified legal counsel, as what you are describing may not be legal in your jurisdiction.